# How to access UserControls from another UserControl.cs page

Tags: c#, button, user-controls

I searched lot. There are lot of questions in stackoverflow like in the above related title but those are not helpfull in my case.

1.I have a **UserControlA.Design.cs** page. In that page i added  my **two UserControls**. Its called "MyUserControl1" and "MyUserControl2".
2. I have a **UserControlB.Design.cs** page.In that page i added my  another UserControl. Its called "MyUserControl3". The MyUserControl3 having Button.I created Button click event in UserControlB.cs page

From this Button click event i have to access the MyUserControl1 from UserControlA.

Give me some idea to solve this. Thanks in advance

**Edit:**

In UserControlA.Design.cs page contains one user control called "MyUserControl1" It contain TreeList. 
In UserControlB.Design.cs page Contains one User Control called 
"MyUserControl2" It contain Button.
Using that button i have to change the state of the datas in treelist. This is what i want to do. Thats why i need Treelist control button click function.

Comment: you can create a static variable of the page that usercontrola is in it and then initialize it on the initialization. 
in usercontrolB, you can access the other control accessing the static variable you created. but it is not the best way to do it. 
Of course this would work only if you had just one instance of usercontrolA

Comment: Hey friend Thanks for your reply, I created static variables but it does n't get the expted result from UserControlB...How can i do this can you help me?

Comment: Could you please send some codes?

Comment: @VahidK., I don't have any codes..So far. Using this controls i have to implements my code here.                                                                                          In UserControlB.cs pg:
        public void Btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {  
          //Have to access my controls here.But can't able.
        }
In UserControlA.cs pg:
public static string  UserControlA;
  I just created static variable.Using this static variable how can i access Controls form UserControlA in UserControlB

Comment: Could you explain what is that you want to do? maybe I can give you a better way to do it?

Comment: Cant you have button and treelist in a specific parent?

Comment: @VahidK. I have a Button in MyUserControl2 and I have a Treelist in MyUserControl1.

Comment: Well, if these two usercontrols are siblings, then what you can do is: add click eventhandler of the button in the parent and change whatever you want in another usercontrol. in the parent of these two, you have the access two all of the children

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to expose the MyUserControl1 from UserControlA via a public property?

Comment: Thanks for your reply,You mean like this:                                                                              public MyUserControl1  UserControlA
        {
            get
            {
                return this.MyUserControl1;
            }
        }                                                                                                               I Just created a property for that in UserControlA.cs page .and how can i able to get these control from Button event?